# How do you deserialize Kryo into case classes using Scalding?

Tags: java, scala, hadoop, kryo, scalding

I know that Scalding's default serialization uses Kryo. So for this example, lets say I have a pipe of student objects.

```
case class Student(name:String, id:String)

val pipe: Pipe[Student] = //....
```

Then I write that pipe to a TextDelimited file using Kryo.

```
pipe.write(args("output"))
```

Now that I have these "output" files, how do I easily read them back into Student objects? My general idea is something like the following but it does not work.

```
Tsv("Kryo output files").read.map {bytes => 
  val instantiator = (new ScalaKryoInstantiator).setRegistrationRequired(true)
  val kryo = instantiator.newKryo

  kryo.register(classOf[Person])

  val deserialized = kryo.readObject(new Input(bytes), classOf[Person])

  deserialized
}
```

How do I deserialize my Kryo written text files into the objects they were originally in?

Comment: Have you found the solution???

Comment: In Scalding, Kryo is the default serialization format so if you use one of Scalding's built in storage formats, Scalding will use Kryo to serialize it. Try SequenceFiles or TSV.